# Flutter - Get Heart Beat from integrated sensor

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sensors

I am new in App developement and started with Flutter. I want to program a litte health app in Flutter which can show the heart beat per minute (BPM). Also, I have my Samsung Galaxy S7, which has an integrated heart beat sensor, as my test Smartphone.

Now I found this package [heart_bpm](https://pub.dev/packages/heart_bpm) but it uses the camera of your smartphone. I expected to be accurate but it is not compared to the integrated sensor in my Samsung Health App

Does anyone of you know how I can use the integrated heart beat sensor of my smartphone?

Thank you very much!

Kind regards,
Bagheer4

Comment: You should search for any SDK that samsung provides for Android to access their health data. Like: https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-sensor-extension/overview.html

Comment: So there isn't any other possibility ?